# What is the intuitive logic behind the working of the Variable Entered K-Map (VEM)?

Tags: boolean-algebra, digital-circuits, karnaugh-map

In this site [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-entrant-map-vem-in-digital-logic/) they have just said how to minimize a function using VEM. But no intuitive logic behind the same has been stated, making it too mechanical. And I am very bad at memorizing things, so an intuitive logic behind the same would help me a lot to solve problems using this problems independently.